# How to add header row to a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, header

I am reading a csv file into pandas. This csv file consists of four columns and some rows, but does not have a header row, which I want to add. I have been trying the following:

```py
Cov = pd.read_csv("path/to/file.txt", sep='\t')
Frame = pd.DataFrame([Cov], columns = ["Sequence", "Start", "End", "Coverage"])
Frame.to_csv("path/to/file.txt", sep='\t')
```

But when I apply the code, I get the following Error:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 1), indices imply (4, 1)
```

What exactly does the error mean? And what would be a clean way in python to add a header row to my csv file/pandas df?

Comment: Here is a different interpretation of your question: Add another header to an existing Dataframe to create a MultiIndex.

Answer (score 446, accepted):

You can use `names` directly in the [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

> names : array-like, default None List of column names to use. If file
>   contains no header row, then you should explicitly pass header=None

```
Cov = pd.read_csv("path/to/file.txt", 
                  sep='\t', 
                  names=["Sequence", "Start", "End", "Coverage"])
```

Answer (score 202):

Alternatively you could read you csv with `header=None` and then add it with `df.columns`:

```
Cov = pd.read_csv("path/to/file.txt", sep='\t', header=None)
Cov.columns = ["Sequence", "Start", "End", "Coverage"]
```

Comment: Code is good -  but I found out that on an empty dataframe it will not work. In that case, Python throws "ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have ... elements". You might need something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44513738/pandas-create-empty-dataframe-with-only-column-names

Answer (score 28):

```
col_Names=["Sequence", "Start", "End", "Coverage"]
my_CSV_File= pd.read_csv("yourCSVFile.csv",names=col_Names)
```

having done this, just check it with:

```
my_CSV_File.head()
```

Answer (score 22):

**Simple And Easy Solution:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("path/to/file.txt", sep='\t')
headers =  ["Sequence", "Start", "End", "Coverage"]
df.columns = headers
```

> **NOTE:** Make sure your header length and CSV file header length should not mismatch.

Comment: I applaud you since you are the only(?) one who actually answered the question instead of suggesting to avoid the problem in the first place

Comment: I believe there is an issue with this solution.

After you read the CSV file, the first row gets declared as the columns. So, when you *re-declare* the columns with the `headers` list, you are not *adding* a new row rather you are replacing the first row (which was declared as a header) with the header list. So you end up removing the literal first row of data.

Answer (score 13):

To fix your code you can simply change `[Cov]` to `Cov.values`, the first parameter of `pd.DataFrame` will become a multi-dimensional `numpy` array:

```
Cov = pd.read_csv("path/to/file.txt", sep='\t')
Frame=pd.DataFrame(Cov.values, columns = ["Sequence", "Start", "End", "Coverage"])
Frame.to_csv("path/to/file.txt", sep='\t')
```

But the smartest solution still is use `pd.read_excel` with `header=None` and `names=columns_list`.

Comment: When we give columns_list, can we add default values for selected columns?

Answer (score 2):

When reading **a file without headers**, existing answers correctly say that `header=` parameter should be set to `None`, but none explain why. It's because by default, `header=0`, which means the first row of the file is inferred as the header. For example, the following code overwrites the first row with `col_names` because the first row was read as the header and it was replaced by `col_names`.

Note that it's assumed that the columns are separated by a space `' '` here.

```py
col_names = ["Sequence", "Start", "End", "Coverage"]
df = pd.read_csv("path/to/file.txt", sep=' ')                   # <--- wrong
df.columns = col_names
```

To get the correct output, you can do one of the following two things:

- set `header=None`:

  ```py
  df = pd.read_csv("path/to/file.txt", sep=' ', header=None)      # <--- OK
  df.columns = col_names
  ```
- or use `names=` parameter to assign column names in one function call:

  ```py
  df = pd.read_csv("path/to/file.txt", sep=' ', names=col_names)  # <--- OK
  ```

`header=None` way is often preferred if the number of columns is not known (because it is important that `len(col_names)` is equal to the number of columns inferred from the file, otherwise only the last column will be read as a column and all preceding rows will be read as index levels) or if the specific column names are not important. For example, calling `add_prefix()` after `read_csv` can add prefix to the default column names:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("path/to/file.txt", sep=' ', header=None).add_prefix('col')
```

---

On the other hand, if **the file has a header**, i.e. first row in the file is meant to be read as column labels, then passing `names=` will push the first row as the first row in the dataframe. In that case, if you want to set the column labels during the `pd.read_csv` call, pass `header=0`.

```py
import io
data = """
ab,bc
10,2.
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), names=['a', 'b'])           # <--- wrong
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), names=['a', 'b'], header=0) # <--- OK
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is mentioned that we are reading from a csv, so the delimiter should be `','[as default, not need to mention]' and the given file has no header so` header=None`

**Sample Code :**

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('path/to/file.txt',header=None)
data.columns = ["Sequence", "Start", "End", "Coverage"]
print(data.head()) #Print the first rows
```