# Adding Column headers to pandas dataframe.. but NAN's all the data even though headers are same dimension

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to add column headers to csv file that I have parsed into a dataframe withing Pandas.

```
dfTrades = pd.read_csv('pnl1.txt',delim_whitespace=True,header=None,);
dfTrades = dfTrades.drop(dfTrades.columns[[3,4,6,8,10,11,13,15,17,18,25,27,29,32]], axis=1)     # Note: zero indexed
dfTrades = dfTrades.set_index([dfTrades.index]);
df = pd.DataFrame(dfTrades,columns=['TradeDate',
                                      'TradeTime',
                                      'CumPnL',
                                      'DailyCumPnL',
                                      'RealisedPnL',
                                      'UnRealisedPnL',
                                      'CCYCCY',
                                      'CCYCCYPnLDaily',
                                      'Position',
                                      'CandleOpen',
                                      'CandleHigh',
                                      'CandleLow',
                                      'CandleClose',
                                      'CandleDir',
                                      'CandleDirSwings',
                                      'TradeAmount',
                                      'Rate',
                                      'PnL/Trade',
                                      'Venue',
                                      'OrderType',
                                      'OrderID'
                                      'Code']);


print df
```

The structure of the data is:

```
01/10/2015 05:47.3  190 190 -648 838 EURNOK -648 0  0 611   -1137   -648 H 2     -1000000   9.465   -648    INTERNAL    IOC 287 AS
```

What Pandas returns is:

```
  TradeDate  TradeTime  CumPnL  DailyCumPnL  RealisedPnL  UnRealisedPnL  \
0            NaN        NaN     NaN          NaN          NaN            NaN   ...
```

I would appreciate any advice on the issue.

Thanks

Ps.
Thanks to Ed for his answer.
I have tried your suggestion with

```
df = dfTrades.columns=['TradeDate',
                   'TradeTime',
                   'CumPnL',
                   'DailyCumPnL',
                   'RealisedPnL',
                   'UnRealisedPnL',
                   'CCYCCY',
                   'CCYCCYPnLDaily',
                   'Position',
                   'CandleOpen',
                   'CandleHigh',
                   'CandleLow',
                   'CandleClose',
                   'CandleDir',
                   'CandleDirSwings',
                   'TradeAmount',
                   'Rate',
                   'PnL/Trade',
                   'Venue',
                   'OrderType',
                   'OrderID'
                   'Code'];
```

But now the problem has morphed to:

```
 ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 22 elements, new values have     21 elements
```

I have taken the shape of the matrix and got:
    dfTrades.shape

```
(12056, 22)
```

So sadly i still need some help :(

Comment: Your last error is clear you have 22 columns but you're trying to pass a list of column names of 21, it's unclear what you expect this to do: `dfTrades.set_index([dfTrades.index]);`

Comment: So what fixed your problem?

Comment: Hi EdChum - Thank you for your help.  Problem fixed, sorry for coming back late.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assign directly to the columns:

```
df.columns = ['TradeDate',
                                      'TradeTime',
                                      'CumPnL',
                                      'DailyCumPnL',
                                      'RealisedPnL',
                                      'UnRealisedPnL',
                                      'CCYCCY',
                                      'CCYCCYPnLDaily',
                                      'Position',
                                      'CandleOpen',
                                      'CandleHigh',
                                      'CandleLow',
                                      'CandleClose',
                                      'CandleDir',
                                      'CandleDirSwings',
                                      'TradeAmount',
                                      'Rate',
                                      'PnL/Trade',
                                      'Venue',
                                      'OrderType',
                                      'OrderID'
                                      'Code']
```

What you're doing is reindexing and because the columns don't agree get all `NaN`s as you're passing the df as the data it will align on existing column names and index values.

You can see the same semantic behaviour here:

```
In [240]:
df = pd.DataFrame(data= np.random.randn(5,3), columns = np.arange(3))
df

Out[240]:
          0         1         2
0  1.037216  0.761995  0.153047
1 -0.602141 -0.114032 -0.323872
2 -1.188986  0.594895 -0.733236
3  0.556196  0.363965 -0.893846
4  0.547791 -0.378287 -1.171706

In [242]:
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = list('abc'))
df1

Out[242]:
    a   b   c
0 NaN NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN
3 NaN NaN NaN
4 NaN NaN NaN
```

Alternatively you can pass the np array as the data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dfTrades.values,columns=['TradeDate',

In [244]:
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.values, columns = list('abc'))
df1

Out[244]:
          a         b         c
0  1.037216  0.761995  0.153047
1 -0.602141 -0.114032 -0.323872
2 -1.188986  0.594895 -0.733236
3  0.556196  0.363965 -0.893846
4  0.547791 -0.378287 -1.171706
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way:
You can use names directly in the `read_csv`

> names : array-like, default None List of column names to use. If the file
>   contains no header row, then you should explicitly pass header=None

```
Cov = pd.read_csv("path/to/file.txt", sep='\t', 
                  names = ["Sequence", "Start", "End", "Coverage"])
Frame=pd.DataFrame([Cov], columns = ["Sequence", "Start", "End", "Coverage"])
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34092032/4818540) answer.

Answer (score 1):

you need to do `dfTrades.values` instead of `dfTrades` when passing to pandas `pd.DataFrame`.

```
column_names= ['TradeDate',
               'TradeTime',
               'CumPnL',
               'DailyCumPnL',
               'RealisedPnL',
               'UnRealisedPnL',
               'CCYCCY',
               'CCYCCYPnLDaily',
               'Position',
               'CandleOpen',
               'CandleHigh',
               'CandleLow',
               'CandleClose',
               'CandleDir',
               'CandleDirSwings',
               'TradeAmount',
               'Rate',
               'PnL/Trade',
               'Venue',
               'OrderType',
               'OrderID'
               'Code']


df1 = pd.DataFrame(dfTrades.values, columns = column_names )

df1.head()
```