# pandas add columns when read from a csv file

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I want to read from a CSV file using pandas `read_csv`. The CSV file doesn't have column names. When I use pandas to read the CSV file, the first row is set as columns by default. But when I use `df.columns = ['ID', 'CODE']`, the first row is gone. I want to add, not replace.

```
df = pd.read_csv(CSV)
df

    a   55000G707270
0   b   5l0000D35270
1   c   5l0000D63630
2   d   5l0000G45630
3   e   5l000G191200
4   f   55000G703240


df.columns=['ID','CODE']
df

    ID          CODE
0   b   5l0000D35270
1   c   5l0000D63630
2   d   5l0000G45630
3   e   5l000G191200
4   f   55000G703240
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add header row to a pandas DataFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34091877/how-to-add-header-row-to-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you need parameter `names` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(CSV, names=['ID','CODE'])
```

> **names** : array-like, default None
>
> List of column names to use. If file contains no header row, then you should explicitly pass header=None. Duplicates in this list are not allowed unless mangle_dupe_cols=True, which is the default.

Answer (score 2):

The reason there are extra index columns add is because to_csv() writes an index per default, so you can either disable index when saving your CSV:

```
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

or you can specify an index column when reading:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', index_col=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may pass the column names at the time of reading the csv file itself as :

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_path, names = ["ID", "CODE"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `names` argument in function call to add the columns yourself:

```
df = pd.read_csv(CSV, names=['ID','CODE'])
```

Answer (score 1):

you need both: `header=None` and `names=['ID','CODE']`, because there are no column names/labels/headers in your CSV file:

```
df = pd.read_csv(CSV, header=None, names=['ID','CODE'])
```