# Pandas create empty DataFrame with only column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dynamic DataFrame which works fine, but when there are no data to be added into the DataFrame I get an error. And therefore I need a solution to create an empty DataFrame with only the column names.

For now I have something like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=COLUMN_NAMES) # Note that there is no row data inserted.
```

PS: It is important that the column names would still appear in a DataFrame.

But when I use it like this I get something like that as a result:

```
Index([], dtype='object')
Empty DataFrame
```

The "Empty DataFrame" part is good! But instead of the Index thing I need to still display the columns.

An important thing that I found out: I am converting this DataFrame to a PDF using Jinja2, so therefore I'm calling out a method to first output it to HTML like that:

```py
df.to_html()
```

This is where the columns get lost I think.

In general, I followed this example: http://pbpython.com/pdf-reports.html. The css is also from the link. That's what I do to send the dataframe to the PDF:

```py
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('.'))
template = env.get_template("pdf_report_template.html")
template_vars = {"my_dataframe": df.to_html()}

html_out = template.render(template_vars)
HTML(string=html_out).write_pdf("my_pdf.pdf", stylesheets=["pdf_report_style.css"])
```

Answer (score 417, accepted):

You can create an empty DataFrame with either column names or an Index:

```
In [4]: import pandas as pd
In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'])
In [6]: df
Out[6]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, C, D, E, F, G]
Index: []
```

Or

```
In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(1,10))
In [8]: df
Out[8]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Edit: 
Even after your amendment with the .to_html, I can't reproduce. This:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'])
df.to_html('test.html')
```

Produces:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
      <th>F</th>
      <th>G</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 20):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
    COLUMN_NAMES=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=COLUMN_NAMES)
    df.columns

   Index(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155776/best-way-to-export-pandas-df-into-a-pdf-file-using-python

Comment: Also, I din't lose my column names when I tried . It is in a html table format.

Answer (score 18):

Creating colnames with `iterating`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['colname_' + str(i) for i in range(5)])
print(df)

# Empty DataFrame
# Columns: [colname_0, colname_1, colname_2, colname_3, colname_4]
# Index: []
```

`to_html()` operations

```
print(df.to_html())

# <table border="1" class="dataframe">
#   <thead>
#     <tr style="text-align: right;">
#       <th></th>
#       <th>colname_0</th>
#       <th>colname_1</th>
#       <th>colname_2</th>
#       <th>colname_3</th>
#       <th>colname_4</th>
#     </tr>
#   </thead>
#   <tbody>
#   </tbody>
# </table>
```

this seems working

```
print(type(df.to_html()))
# <class 'str'>
```

#### The problem is caused by

when you create df like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=COLUMN_NAMES)
```

it has `0 rows × n columns`, you need to create at least one row index by

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=COLUMN_NAMES, index=[0])
```

now it has `1 rows × n columns`. You are be able to add data. Otherwise its df that only consist  colnames  object(like a string list).

Comment: Massive thanks to you. I struggled with not being able to add data for 2 hours

Answer (score 3):

`df.to_html()` has a columns parameter.

Just pass the columns into the `to_html()` method.

```
df.to_html(columns=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a completely empty dataframe without columns or index, you can let it have columns by assigning `None` to these columns.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()                    # <---- shape: (0, 0)
df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']] = None    # <---- shape: (0, 3)
```

Then to assign a row to it, you can use `loc` indexer. This can actually be used in a loop to add more rows (something that's inadvisable as `pd.concat` exists to do that particular task).

```py
df.loc[len(df)] = ['abc', 10, 3.33]    # <---- shape: (1, 3)
```

[image: res]