# Python Pandas declaration empty DataFrame only with columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to declare empty dataframe in python in order to append it later in a loop. Below the line of the declaration:

```
 result_table = pd.DataFrame([[], [], [], [], []], columns = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])
```

It throws an error:

> AssertionError: 5 columns passed, passed data had 0 columns

Why is it so? I tried to find out the solution, but I failed.

Comment: It seems you need `result_table = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"] )`

Comment: The direct question has been answered... but the main question is "why do you want to append to it later"?

Comment: Can you explain how do you want in loop create rows? I think it is not good idea, the best is fill lists and then once call DataFrame constructor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas create empty DataFrame with only column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44513738/pandas-create-empty-dataframe-with-only-column-names)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C','D','E'])
```

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Because you actually pass no data. Try this

```
result_frame = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
```

if you then want to add data, use

```
result_frame.loc[len(result_frame)] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to create a `list` or `tuple`s or `list`s and then call `DataFrame` only once:

```
L = []
for i in range(3):
    #some random data  
    a = 1
    b = i + 2
    c = i - b
    d = i
    e = 10
    L.append((a, b, c, d, e))

print (L)
[(1, 2, -2, 0, 10), (1, 3, -2, 1, 10), (1, 4, -2, 2, 10)]

result_table = pd.DataFrame(L, columns = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])
print (result_table) 
   A  B  C  D   E
0  1  2 -2  0  10
1  1  3 -2  1  10
2  1  4 -2  2  10
```