# Manually set the keys in Pandas DataFrame built with read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a .tsv file dataset, and I transformed it into a DataFrame using Pandas.
Imagine that my_tsv_file was something like:

```
A Apple
B Orange
C Pear
```

To build the DataFrame I used:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(my_tsv_file, sep='\t')
```

Now, the first row of my_tsv_file was originally a row part of the data, but it has been transformed to the "key row" in the new DataFrame. So now the Dataframe is something like:

```
      A Apple
   0  B Orange
   1  C Pear
```

As "A" and "Apple" were keys, when they actually are not. I would like to add the correct "key row", in order to obtain something like:

```
      ID Fruit
   0  A  Apple
   1  B  Orange
   2  C  Pear
```

How can I achieve this?
I can't modify the original .tsv file.
Please remind that I am at the very beginning with Python and Pandas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add header row to a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34091877/how-to-add-header-row-to-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried

`df = pandas.read_csv(my_tsv_file, sep='\t', names=['ID', 'Fruit'])`

Comment: I don't think you need to do that, by supplying `names` pandas will understand there is no header

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know this option, is exactly what I was looking for