# Pandas, making a dataframe based on the length of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert `df` to just get the length of it in a new dataframe.
Which is what I do, but then this dataframe does not have a header.
How do I add a header to this length?

```
            df = df.append(df_temp, ignore_index=True, sort=True)
            df = len(df)
```

when I print `df` i get the # of records but no header. How can I add a header to this?

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34091877/how-to-add-header-row-to-a-pandas-dataframe) from stackoverflow can help you out

Comment: `df = len(df)` returns an integer not dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to your `df` have the column name and the lenght then you shuld try something like:

```
labels = {}
for column in temp_df.columns:
    labels[column] = len(temp_df[column].dropna())
print(labels)
```

Here `labels` would be a dictionary with the column name as a key and the number of rows as a value.