# KeyError: 'date' in format dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: datetime, parsing, jupyter-notebook, keyerror, python-3.11

```
#read the data in csv
df_sales = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Yuvraj\\Downloads\\sales_data.csv",'utf-8')
#convert date field from string to datetime
df_sales = {1: "date", 2: "store", 3: "item", 4:"sales"}
df_sales['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_sales['date'])

#show first 10 rows
df_sales.head(10)
```

was trying to convert 'date' field from string to datetime

This is the output : KeyError: 'date'

what do I do?

Comment: First you read a data frame into `df_sales` and in the second step you overwrite it with a dict that only contains the keys 1, 2 and 3. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/34092032/18667225

Answer (score 0):

`'date'` is not in your dict as key, it's a value of `key = 1`.

So, you can't do `df_sales["date"]`, it raises `KeyError`.