# How can I add data to the first row specifically in a non-empty csv file?

Tags: python, csv

```
from csv import  *

items = ["Lenovo",1500,"Laptop"]

#using writer

with open("items.csv","a") as writable:
    written = writer(writable)
    written.writerow(items)
    writable.close()
```

I had done this so far but this adds to the last row.

Comment: Typically you want to append to the end rather than prepend to the start so you will have to manually do this yourself. Read the file into a list, re-open the file in "w" mode write the new first then write the rest.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer to a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34091877/how-to-add-header-row-to-a-pandas-dataframe) also listed on SO

Answer (score 0):

Like [JonSG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218663/jonsg) commented, a very straightforward approach is to:

1. read the file into a list of rows
2. insert/prepend the row you care about
3. write the list out

With Python's csv module and the basic reader and writer, that looks something like the following:

```py
import csv

new_row = ["Lenovo", 1500, "Laptop"]

with open("input.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)

data.insert(1, new_row)

with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

If I start with:

```
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
|------|------|------|
| r1c1 | r1c2 | r1c3 |
| r2c1 | r2c2 | r2c3 |
| r3c1 | r3c2 | r3c3 |
```

I end up with:

```
| Col1   | Col2 | Col3   |
|--------|------|--------|
| Lenovo | 1500 | Laptop |
| r1c1   | r1c2 | r1c3   |
| r2c1   | r2c2 | r2c3   |
| r3c1   | r3c2 | r3c3   |
```

My sample CSV has a header, index 0, so I inserted the new row at index 1 (the first "row of data").

(I always recommend writing to a new file, making sure you like the result, then move/rename it to the original once your satisfied... at least when you're getting started.)

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward way to add a line to the beginning of a file is to simply read the whole file, rewind, write the line, then re-write the data.  No need for csv parsing at all and will likely be faster.

```py
with open('items.csv', 'r+') as file:
    data = file.read()
    file.seek(0)
    file.write('Lenovo,1500,Laptop\n')
    file.write(data)
```